# Task Space Vs. Configuration Space

Tags: robotics

In robotics, what is the difference between Task Space and Configuration Space?

I know that the configuration Space is the set of all reachable configurations for the robot. But I am not sure what does Task Space represent.

Comment: What did you find when you googled?

Comment: And what is Work Space in comparison to them?

Comment: In some references I found them saying "configuration space refers to the set of positions reachable by a robot's end-effector" while in others it was defined as "Set of all possible configurations"

Comment: Now I am confused between the following three terms: Configuration Space - Task Space - Work Space

Comment: I found the answer:
Configuration Space: Set of all possible configurations. 
Task Space: Set of all possible poses. 
Work Space: Set of all points reachable by the end-effector.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't include anything related to programming or software - and while it's of interest, the mathematics / robotics / theoretical computer science communities would all be able to provide much more detailed / specific answers.